# How to remove package that is not install?

Tags: centos, yum

I was run this command.

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

But I cannot install node.js or it is too old (0.xx while currently on website it is 4.xx)

Now, I try to remove it using `yum remove nodejs` but it said

> Package(s) nodejs available, but not installed.

How do i remove this completely?
My OS is: CentOS 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't install the package with yum or rpm, you also can't remove it with yum.

Yum is essentially telling that the package is available in the repository but it's not installed.

To remove node.js just delete it from where you downloaded it to.

Comment: how do i know where because I use curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash - and it doesn't tell me where.

Comment: @vee, it will download it to whichever directory you ran the `curl` command in.

Comment: @Elias Regarding "If you didn't install the package with yum you also can't remove it with yum." - that is not always true, if I would have installed a package with rpm directly I would still be able to remove it with yum ;)

Comment: @doktor5000 You are right of course, I will edit my answer to mention that.